# Why do qqnorm and qqline endpoints not coincide on qqplot?

Tags: r, statistics, probability

This is my R code:

```
H1_BCSE <- c(172,181,171,170,174,177,178,165,169,168,171,180,170,172,170,178,163,169,170,175,170,176,176)
#Histogram
length(H)
hist(H)
#QQplot
#qqplot
qqnorm(H1_BCSE)
qqline(H1_BCSE)
```

[QQPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKjYY.png) 
So why is there a difference in the position of the 2 red points in the plot?

Answer (score 0):

From `?qqline`:

> [the] quantile-quantile plot...passes through the probs quantiles, by
> default the first and third quartiles.

You didn't specify any quantiles, so the `probs` argument defaulted to `c(0.25, 0.75)`.

I would be hesitant to use the endpoints for a quantile-quantile plot since that's where outliers end up.